# Get previous rows and next rows of linq result for special row

Tags: linq, entity-framework, linq-to-entities

I have a list of profile each profile have a own point how can I show a list that shows previous profiles(rows) and next profiles.

For example:

```
a 20
b 30
c 40 
d 50
e 60 
f 70
v 80 
t 90
```

my goal is d but I want to show two previous rows and two next in list, too:

```
b 30
c 40
d 50
e 60
f 70
```

Comment: Do you have anymore info as to how you are retreiving `d` now?

Comment: *Previous* and *next* imply an **ordering** - what do you want to have your rows **ordered by** ?

Comment: Punctuation. Beautiful invention. Further, what type of list is this? Is there always 1 `d`? Looks like you could use IndexOf -/+ 2.

Comment: I solved that but I used extra objects.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my goal ProfileId will be parameter. I retrieved whatever I wanted.

```
// here is my code.
var pp = from p in db.Profiles.OrderByDescending(u => u.score) select p; 

foreach(var x in pp)
{
    t++;
    if (x.ProfileId == 58)
    {
        r = t;
    }
}
var zz = from d in pp.Skip(r - 2).Take(4) select d;
```